# Stochastic Integral of Particle Scattering

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales

I have a stochastic process that describes a particle moving through a field of randomly distributed particles and undergoing scattering collisions (modeled simplistically) off of them.  In its simplest form, the equation is

$$
\Delta \vec{v} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\left[k_1\frac{\hat{x}\,\rm{cos}\,\theta_i + \hat{y}\,\rm{sin}\,\theta_i}{\sqrt{b_i}}+k_2\frac{\hat z}{b_i}\right]
$$

with randomly chosen variables

$$
b_i = \rm{rand}\left[0,b_\rm{max}\right]\, ,\,\, \theta_i = \rm{rand}\left[0,2\pi\right]
$$

I am looking to find a function that describes the probability distribution of this process.  I don't know how to do a stochastic integral analytically but I did a numerical calculation with $k_1=k_2=b_\rm{max}=1, N = 10^4$ and the distribution that I found is shown in the image below.  The numerical solution is a good start, but I would like to have something that is a function of the input variables.

Numerical solution:
[numerical solution plot http://www.rearviewminor.com/logdistribution3.png](http://www.rearviewminor.com/logdistribution3.png).

Is it possible to find an analytic solution that describes the 2-D probability distribution of this process?  And if so, how is this accomplished?  I've tried reading some literature on stochastic calculus but as it's not typically a part of my field I have a difficult time understanding the syntax and lingo.

Thank you!

Edit: Since I received a few upvotes for this question, but no answer, I've [asked another question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593120/probability-distribution-of-the-sum-of-the-inverses-of-n-random-variables-unifor) that is maybe a simplified version of this one.

Comment: Pdf of $g=\frac 1 {\sqrt {b_i}}$ is $\frac 2 {t^3b_{max}^2}$ on $[\frac 1{\sqrt{b_{max}}},\infty)$ which is in the attraction domain of normal distribution, so $$(\frac {v_x}{\sqrt{n\log n}},\frac {v_y}{\sqrt{n\log n}})\overset{d}\to N(0,\Sigma)$$ where $\Sigma$ is diagonal matrix with equal entries which can be easily computed. Distribution of $v_z$ was derived in the other post.

Comment: Thank you @A.S., I will try to work through this. If I am able to find (or approximate) the distributions of both $\Delta v_\bot = \frac{1}{N}\left|\sum_i^N \frac{\hat{x}\,\rm{cos}\,\theta_i + \hat{y}\,\rm{sin}\,\theta_i}{\sqrt{b_i}}\right|$ and $\Delta v_\parallel = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N\frac{1}{b_i}$ am I able to do a multivariate convolution of the two to find the 2D distribution or do convolutions only work for 1 variable?

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, it would not be possible to recreate the original distribution from the distributions along the individual dimensions.

Comment: Well, you know that $v_x$ and $v_y$ are independent, but I haven't worked out their dependence with $v_z$.