# Distribution of sums of inverses of random variables uniformly distributed on [0,1]

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, law-of-large-numbers

If I have $N$ random variables (denoted below as $X_i$) with uniform distribution on the $x$-axis $X_i = \rm{rand}[0,1]$ then the sum

$$
S_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\frac{1}{2X_i-1}
$$

seems to be a [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) with $\gamma = \pi/2$.  I found this by trial and error.
$$
f_{S_N}(x)=\frac2{4x^2 + \pi^2}
$$

The plot of the distribution along with the ideal Cauchy distribution is shown below for $N=200$, with data accumulated from $10^5$ trials.

[Cauchy Distribution http://www.rearviewminor.com/cauchydist2.png](http://www.rearviewminor.com/cauchydist2.png)

However, what I would really like to find is the probability distribution of

$$
T_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i^N\frac{1}{X_i}
$$

with the same flat random variable distribution $X_i = \rm{rand}[0,1]$ as above.  For different values of $N$ (the distribution is no longer independent of $N$ like the first distribution) the distributions of $T_N-\log N$ are plotted, showing a convergence for large $N$.

[Some Other Distribution http://www.rearviewminor.com/unknowndistshift2.png](http://www.rearviewminor.com/unknowndistshift2.png)

All of the distributions seem to have right tails that go as $x^{-2}$, which makes sense in light of A.S.'s comment.  Does anyone recognize what distribution this might be?  Or better yet, teach a man to fish: how does one go from a sum of random variables to figuring out what the probability distribution is?

So far I have been doing some reading around on Wikipedia, and I found [this pdf](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) helpful, but I am still stuck.  Solving this will ideally be a stepping stone on my road to finding an answer to [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587071/stochastic-integral-of-particle-scattering).

Comment: It look somewhat similar to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution

Comment: I had thought of that, but this distribution seems to stay near zero for longer before shooting up to its peak, and it also seems to have a more significant tail.  [Here is a plot of a Maxwell-Boltzmann superimposed as a comparison.](http://www.rearviewminor.com/maxwellfit.png)

Comment: It also resembles a log-normal distribution or an Inverse Gaussian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution)

Comment: Corrected the tags and some notational incoherences in the question. In the motivating part, note that no $S_N$ is exactly Cauchy but that, indeed, $S_N$ may converge in distribution to a Cauchy distribution when $N\to\infty$. In the second part, note that, by construction, $T_N\geqslant1$ almost surely hence, if $f_{T_n}\to f_T$ pointwise for some PDF $f_T$, then $f_T(t)=0$ for every $t<1$.

Comment: Pdf of $Y=\frac 1 X$ is $f_Y(y)=\frac 1 {y^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$, so it has Paretian tail $\alpha=1$ (just like Cauchy) and hence by Generalized Central Limit Theorem (Kolmogorov-Gnedenko), $T_N-\log N\overset{d}\to\zeta$ where $\zeta$ is some 1-stable law with $\beta=1$ (maximally skewed) (in your first symmetric scenario, $\beta=0$, so centering constant is $0$ and limiting distribution is Cauchy). I'm not sure about location parameter - it's either zero or close to 0. Note that $\zeta$ has a right paretian tail $\alpha=1$ and the left tail vanishes.

Comment: Since this is a field I am not familiar with, could you explain to me what $T_N-\log N\overset{d}\to\zeta$ means?  Perhaps from there I can learn by rooting around through Wikipedia and other sources.  Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to do with the fact that the peak of each curve happens near $\log N$, at least for the larger values of $N$?

Comment: Use "@A.S." when replying so that I receive a notification. $G_n=T_N-\log N\overset{d}\to\zeta$ means that $T_N-\log N$ converges "in distribution" - that is if you plot this for large values of $N$, the density of $G_n$ will approach that of $\zeta$. So intead of plotting $T_N$ for different $N$, you should plot $T_N-\log N$ to see the convergence (you can already see that T=1000 and T=100 have almost the same shape and differ by a translation of $\log 10$ only). There is no nicer way to describe 1-stable law then I did - though you can write down its characteristic function explicitly.